# How to retrieve method type inside a package?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

How can I get the type of the method (whether it's a FUNCTION or a PROCEDURE) inside a package?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SAMPLE_PACKAGE IS

PROCEDURE procedure1;

PROCEDURE procedure2;

FUNCTION function1(
  key_           IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN;

END SAMPLE_PACKAGE;
```

My package will be like this, it will have multiple Functions and Procedures.

I tried examples like [How do I differentiate between Procedures and Functions in Oracle's Metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799653/how-do-i-differentiate-between-procedures-and-functions-in-oracles-metadata) using user_arguments and user_procedures tables but it seems to be costly when it comes to a large data set

```
SELECT up.object_name, up.procedure_name, up.overload,
CASE WHEN ua.object_id IS NULL THEN 'PROCEDURE' ELSE 'FUNCTION' END AS method_type
FROM user_procedures up LEFT JOIN user_arguments ua ON ( ua.object_id = up.object_id
         AND ua.subprogram_id = up.subprogram_id AND ua.position = 0 )
WHERE up.object_name = 'MY_OBJECT';
```

Comment: Create a materialized view out from `user_procedures up LEFT JOIN user_arguments`

Answer (score 0):

```
select object_name, object_type, name, type
from user_identifiers
where  object_type like 'PACKAGE%'
and usage in ('DECLARATION', 'DEFINITION')
and type in ('FUNCTION', 'PROCEDURE');
```

This simple query returns all user defined packages. Feel free to filter out what you need.

Comment: Hi @CzarLazar thanks for the response. Unfortunately this doesn't work for custom schemas and my requirement is to get info about methods declared within packages.